# Extra points appearing at Frame while using Mesh with ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting

Consider this `ListLinePlot`

```
ListLinePlot[Exp[#] & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.05], PlotRange -> {1, 2}, 
             Frame -> True, Mesh -> Full]
```

[image]

How to get rid of this extra on the upper frame?
(Is it a bug!)

One walk around is using a suitable `PlotRangePadding` along y axis, but I want to avoid that (because I have a lot of sets with different range and I don't want to specify different padding for each of them manually)

This does not appear if I use `PlotMarkers` instead of `Mesh`.

```
ListLinePlot[Exp[#] & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.05], PlotRange -> {1, 2}, 
              Frame -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}]
```

[image]

Is it possible to get the same output with `Mesh`?

Comment: As a reminder: when asking about unexpected behavior, it is customary to include the version number and the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround:

```
ListLinePlot[Exp[#] & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.05],
  PlotRange -> {1, 2},
  Frame -> True,
  Mesh -> All] /. Point[{a__, _, b_}] :> Point[{a, b}]
```

[image]

Use `Mesh -> All` and delete the next to last point